# UDP server doesn't receive packets

Tags: sockets, udp, boost-asio

I’m trying to create simple UDP server, so I modified one of daytime example. Basically, I want to send a packet and receive the response from device, directly connected via cable. The problem is, I can see sent and received packet via Wireshark, but my program doesn’t see incoming packet.

Also I want to mention, that my payload data is 9-10 bytes, because I’m little concerned if I should add some padding. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

class udp_server {
public:
    udp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : socket_(io_service, , udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 13)) {
       send_buf  = { 0xEF, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
       receiver_endpoint_ = udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::broadcast(), 8888);
       socket_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));
       socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
       start_send();
    }

private:
    void start_receive() {
       socket_.async_receive_from(
           boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), sender_endpoint_,
           boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, this,
                       boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                       boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void start_send() {
           rand_buf();

           socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(send_buf), receiver_endpoint_,
                                 boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_send, this, send_buf,
                                             boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                             boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }

    void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                       std::size_t b/*bytes_transferred*/) {
       if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size) {
           std::cout << "rcv: " << b << "\n";
            start_send();
       }
    }

    void handle_send(boost::array<unsigned char, 9>& /*message*/,
                    const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
                    std::size_t b/*bytes_transferred*/) {
       std::cout << "snt: " << b << "\n";
       start_receive();
    }

    void rand_buf() {
    // randomize last 4 bytes
       send_buf[5] = rand() % 0xFF;
       send_buf[6] = rand() % 0xFF;
       send_buf[7] = rand() % 0xFF;
       send_buf[8] = rand() % 0xFF;
    }

    udp::socket socket_;
    udp::endpoint receiver_endpoint_;
    udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
    boost::array<char, 64> recv_buffer_;
    boost::array<unsigned char, 9> send_buf;
};

int main() {
    try {
       boost::asio::io_service io_service;
       udp_server server(io_service);
       io_service.run();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
       std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Solved if myself. Problem was, that I forgot to add port to listen in socket_ in constructor

Comment: If you are just starting learning sockets, why are you using boost::asio? This is extremely complicated library. You'd be much better off with a simple BSD socket API.

Comment: `1.2.3.4` isn't likely to be a valid endpoint. Use `0.0.0.0` for the receiving socket, and `127.0.0.1` as the target address.

Comment: SergeyA, this is a starting point. Complexity isn't an issue here.

Comment: Thanks, EJP, but does it make any difference, that Wireshark shows me sent and received packet? Changed to broadcast address, but problem is still the same.

Comment: What platform are you on?  Wireshark (and tcpdump) will see packets that arrive at the kernel but are filtered off later, either by your firewall or by reverse path filtering.